# Share Parcelable object from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, parcelable

Hello i try to pass object from Fragment to Activity like next:

```
 Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
 bundle1.putParcelable("company", companies.get(i));
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyInfoActivity.class);
 intent.putExtras(bundle1);
 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

And in Activity i make next:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 company = bundle.getParcelable("company");
```

And i Try:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyInfoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("company",companies.get(i));
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

And in Activity:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    company = intent.getParcelableExtra("company");
    tvName.setText(company.getName());
```

And `company` is with null fields after i get it. I am sure that object, which I sent is not with null fields.

My Company.class

```
public class Company implements Parcelable {

private int uid;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_name_value")
private String name;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_address_value")
private String address;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_category_tid")
private int category;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_town_tid")
private int cityId;
@SerializedName("image")
private String imageUrl;
private int online;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_description_value")
private String description;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_phone_value")
private String mobPhone;
@SerializedName("field_user_org_stac_phone_value")
private String phone;

double lat;
double lng = 0;
double distance;


public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public double getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(double lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getMobPhone() {
    return mobPhone;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public int getOnline() {
    return online;
}


public Company(int id, String name, String address, int category, int cityId, String imageUrl, int online, String description, String mobPhone, String phone, Double lat, Double lng, Double distance) {
    this.uid = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.category = category;
    this.cityId = cityId;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.online = online;
    this.description = description;
    this.mobPhone = mobPhone;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.distance = distance;
}

public Company(Parcel in) {
    in.writeInt(uid);
    in.writeString(name);
    in.writeString(address);
    in.writeInt(category);
    in.writeInt(cityId);
    in.writeString(imageUrl);
    in.writeInt(online);
    in.writeString(description);
    in.writeString(mobPhone);
    in.writeString(phone);
    in.writeDouble(lat);
    in.writeDouble(lng);
    in.writeDouble(distance);

}

public int getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public int getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public int getCityId() {
    return cityId;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(uid);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(address);
    dest.writeInt(category);
    dest.writeInt(cityId);
    dest.writeString(imageUrl);
    dest.writeInt(online);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(mobPhone);
    dest.writeString(phone);
    dest.writeDouble(lat);
    dest.writeDouble(lng);
    dest.writeDouble(distance);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

    @Override
    public Object createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Company(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Company[size];
    }
};


public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Company> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Company o1, Company o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}

public static class CustomComparatorDistance implements Comparator<Company> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Company o1, Company o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.getDistance(), o2.getDistance());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: i know this, but it is not comunication between activity and fragment.

Comment: Maybe try serializable instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this piece of code

```
public Company(Parcel in) {
    in.writeInt(uid);
    in.writeString(name);
    in.writeString(address);
    in.writeInt(category);
    in.writeInt(cityId);
    in.writeString(imageUrl);
    in.writeInt(online);
    in.writeString(description);
    in.writeString(mobPhone);
    in.writeString(phone);
    in.writeDouble(lat);
    in.writeDouble(lng);
    in.writeDouble(distance);

}
```

you should read values from parcel:

```
uid = in.readInt();
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your implementation of `Parcelable` -- particularly your `Parcel` constructor:

```
public Company(Parcel in) {
    in.writeInt(uid);
    in.writeString(name);
    ...
}
```

You're writing fields *to* the `Parcel` in your constructor. This is the point where you need to *read in* the data from the `Parcel` into the object you're creating. For example:

```
public Company(Parcel in) {
    uid = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but Aleksandr Zhak write this answer 1 minute earlier

Answer (score -2):

You can create a listener to communicate between your fragment and your activity :

```
public interface CompanyListener
{
    public void sendCompany(Company company);
}
```

Next, in your Fragment you have to create an instance of this listener

```
private CompanyListener companyListener;
```

In the `OnAttach` you have to instantiate it and uninstantiate it in the `OnDetach`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.companyListener = (YourActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
    this.companyListener = null;
}
```

Now you just have to implement it in your activity.

Also you can use [Otto library from Square](http://square.github.io/otto/) but it's more complicated :)

Comment: I don't want to set minus to your answer, but read more carefull my question, i want to start NEW sctivity from fragment and pass data to it