# Parcelable with arraylist<string> passing value from activity to fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, parcelable

i need to send arraylist value from fragment to activity. I have tried with few codes but the return value is null.any help with code or tutorial of parcelable for `arraylist<string>` passing value from activity to fragment.

here's my code for passing arraylist :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key", selectImages);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
```

here's Myparcelable class code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ObjectA implements Parcelable {

    public ArrayList<String> choices;

   public ObjectA (ArrayList<String> choices) {
             this.choices = choices;
    }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ObjectA (Parcel parcel) {
          parcel.readArrayList(null);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
         dest.writeStringList(choices);
    }

    // Method to recreate a ObjectA from a Parcel
    public static Creator<ObjectA> CREATOR = new Creator<ObjectA>() {

        @Override
        public ObjectA createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ObjectA(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectA[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ObjectA[size];
        }
    };    
    }
```

here's code that used to extract in fragment(making it to display just to check the value):

```
    ArrayList<String> ar1 =  getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Path of array in home Fragment: "+ar1,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

when i run the code the return value is null for ar1. where am i making mistake?

thanks,

Comment: are you gettting `key` from intent in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: yes but still key value is null.

Comment: You should read values from parcel in constructor, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856267/share-parcelable-object-from-fragment-to-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            if (requestCode == 999) {           
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<String> ar1 =  data.getStringArrayListExtra("key"); 
                if(ar1.size()!= 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < ar1.size(); i++) {
                    String value = ar1.get(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Path of array in home Fragment: "+ar1,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }       }      }     }
```

Missed this Line: `ArrayList<String> ar1 =  data.getStringArrayListExtra("key");` 
thanks for the help